# How to transfer ERC20 tokens from an account to a contract?

Tags: solidity

I'm struggling to transfer my ERC20 token toward a contract address.
My code is like this. What's wrong with my code? the code is like this.

```
Contract A{
  function deposit(uint amount) public {
    ERC20.transfer(address(this), amount);
  }
}
```

I have confirmed contract type ERC20 is valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ERC20 requires two transactions for transferring:

1. account `approve`s an allowance for Contract A
2. account then calls Contract A where Contract A calls `transferFrom` with an amount within the allowance.

The issue with your code is that you are using `transfer` rather than `transferFrom` and you need to set an allowance.

If you are creating ERC20 tokens you may want to look at the OpenZeppelin Contracts implementation to see if this meets your needs. See the documentation for details: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/tokens#ERC20

Alternatively you could look at creating ERC777 tokens (no need to do approve and transferFrom in two separate transactions). See the documentation for details: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/tokens#ERC777

If you have questions on using OpenZeppelin you can ask in the Community Forum: https://forum.openzeppelin.com/

Disclosure: I am the Community Manager at OpenZeppelin

Comment: Thanks for replying! I'd like to ask one more question. How can I do those two actions from my front-end thru web3.js? are there any examples??

Comment: Your users will have to do two transactions.  First approve an allowance on the token contract and then call the deposit function.